# How to properly decode nested JSON objects with Swift structs

Tags: json, swift, swift-dictionary, swift-structs

**Intent:**

Receive cryptocurrency price data via [Coinmarketcap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1ToolsPriceconversion), decode it into custom structs in SWIFT and potentially store that data in a database (either CoreData or SQLite).

**Context:**

I am receiving the following error on `JSONDecoder().decode`:

```
Error serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "status", intValue: nil), _DictionaryCodingKey(stringValue: "credit_count", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

**Questions:**

1. How to properly interpret that error? What am I decoding wrong?
2. Is the data I am receiving correctly formatted? Doesn't look like
   proper JSON.

**The code:**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// Defining structures

struct RootObject: Decodable {
    let status: [String: StatusObject?]
    let data: DataObject?
}

struct StatusObject: Decodable {
    let credit_count: Int?
    let elapsed: Int?
    let error_code: Int?
    let timestamp: String?
}

struct DataObject: Decodable {
    let amount: Int?
    let id: Int?
    let last_updated: String?
    let name: String?
    let quote: [QuoteObject]?
    let symbol: String?
}

struct QuoteObject: Decodable {
    let usd: String?
}

struct usdObject: Decodable {
    let last_updated: String?
    let price: String?
}


//Configuring URLSession

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "<removed>",
                                "Accept": "application/json",
                                "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip"]

let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let url = URL(string: "https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/tools/price-conversion?convert=USD&amount=1&symbol=BTC")!


//Making and handling a request

let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        print ("error: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    guard let content = data else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }

    //Serializing and displaying the received data
    guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any]
    else {
        print("Not containing JSON")
        return
    }

    print(json)

    //Trying to decode
    do {
        let prices = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootObject.self, from: data!)
        print(prices)
    } catch let decodeError {
        print("Error serializing json:", decodeError)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

**The data response and the error:**

```
["status": {
    "credit_count" = 1;
    elapsed = 6;
    "error_code" = 0;
    "error_message" = "<null>";
    timestamp = "2019-02-16T11:10:22.147Z";
}, "data": {
    amount = 1;
    id = 1;
    "last_updated" = "2018-12-22T06:08:23.000Z";
    name = Bitcoin;
    quote =     {
        USD =         {
            "last_updated" = "2018-12-22T06:08:23.000Z";
            price = "3881.88864625";
        };
    };
    symbol = BTC;
}]
Error serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "status", intValue: nil), _DictionaryCodingKey(stringValue: "credit_count", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

**Edit 1:**

Properly serialized JSON:

```
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-16T18:54:05.499Z",
        "error_code": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "elapsed": 6,
        "credit_count": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "amount": 1,
        "last_updated": "2018-12-22T06:08:23.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 3881.88864625,
                "last_updated": "2018-12-22T06:08:23.000Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SE cuts away "Hi" for some reason :/

Comment: The question should not be chatty, filled with "Hi" and "thanks" and stuff like that, because they are considered noise. That's why "Hi" got removed.

Comment: That is not valid json, could you post the original json message

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, question moderated

Comment: @ayaio Thanks, fixed that

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Added proper JSON to the question. Answer by vadian is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in the structs.

The main issue is that the value for `data` is a dictionary which is decoded into a struct rather than into another dictionary. Other issues are that the type of `id` is `String` and `price` is `Double`.

APIs like `Coinmarketcap` send reliable data so don't declare everything as optional. Remove the question marks.

The structs below are able to decode the JSON. The quotes are decoded into a dictionary because the keys change. Add the `.convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy to get *camelCased* keys. The dates are decoded as `Date` by adding an appropriate date decoding strategy.

I removed all those redundant `...Object` occurrences except `DataObject` because the `Data` struct already exists.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let status: Status
    let data: DataObject
}

struct Status: Decodable {
    let creditCount: Int
    let elapsed: Int
    let errorCode: Int
    let timestamp: Date
}

struct DataObject: Decodable {
    let amount: Int
    let id: String
    let lastUpdated: Date
    let name: String
    let quote: [String:Quote]
    let symbol: String
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    let lastUpdated: Date
    let price: Double
}


//Trying to decode
do {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
    let quotes = result.data.quote
    for (symbol, quote) in quotes {
        print(symbol, quote.price)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vadian! Also, the key `DataObject.id` needed to be changed from `String` to `Int`

Comment: I used the sample response on the linked site where `id` is clearly a string (value in double quotes). And the documentation says it's string, too. By the way: If you specify to get a UNIX timestamp as date you can omit the custom date formatter.

Comment: Correct, they show it as String there, but it produced an error:

`typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Can it be an error in the Docs?

Comment: Could be. The actual data counts. Please ask the operator of the service